# Set y position when drawing rectangles with qpainter

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I'm drawing waveforms using QPainter and I moved from displaying a single channel to displaying both if they are available. Managed to draw the first channel at the top of my canvas but I got no luck for the second channel.

The drawRect function for 1 channel would be:

`painter.drawRect(i * xScale, center - (m_samplesL[i] * center), 2, (m_samplesL[i] * center) * 2);`

Which will draw it in the middle.

Now for the other two channels. The following works for the first channel:

`painter.drawRect(i * xScale, (center / 2) - (m_samplesL[i] * (center / 2)), 2, (m_samplesL[i] * (center / 2)) * 2);`

Here there are some arguments changed, `y` position and `h` height.

For the second channel I though it will make sense to change the `y` value, instead of `(center / 2)` to make it `(center * 2)` so it will push the waveform of the second channel at the bottom while keeping the height of the first channel.

`painter.drawRect(i * xScale, ((center * 2)) - (m_samplesR[i] * (center / 2)), 2, (m_samplesR[i] * (center / 2)) * 2);`

But the position of the waveform of the second channel is way far away from the bottom of the widget. As seen in the screenshot below.

Will also post the code below. The drawing of the waveform is made in another threaded function as nothing is wrong with the main code that gets the data and stores it in the WaveformThread widget.

[image]

WaveformThread.h

```
#ifndef WAVEFORMTHREAD_H
#define WAVEFORMTHREAD_H

#include <QMutex>
#include <QThread>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QImage>
#include <QVector>
#include <QPainter>

class WaveformThread : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    WaveformThread();
    ~WaveformThread();
    void storeSamples(const QVector<double> &samples);
    void storeSamples(const QVector<double> &samplesR, const QVector<double> &samplesL);
    void setChannelCount(int channels);
    void deleteSamples();
    void processSamples(qreal window_wdith, qreal window_height, QColor wave_color, QColor background_color);
    void stopProcess();
private:
    QMutex mutex;
    bool m_abort;

    QVector<double> m_samples;
    QVector<double> m_samplesR;
    QVector<double> m_samplesL;
    int m_channelCount = 1;
    qreal m_width;
    qreal m_heihgt;
    QColor m_wave_color;
    QColor m_background_color;
protected:
    void run();
signals:
    void waveformReady(QImage);
};

#endif // WAVEFORMTHREAD_H
```

WaveformThread.cpp

```
#include "waveformthread.h"

WaveformThread::WaveformThread()
{
    m_abort = false;
}

WaveformThread::~WaveformThread()
{
    mutex.lock();
    m_abort = true;
    mutex.unlock();

    wait();
}

void WaveformThread::storeSamples(const QVector<double> &samples)
{
    m_samplesL = samples;
}

void WaveformThread::storeSamples(const QVector<double> &samplesR, const QVector<double> &samplesL)
{
    m_samplesR = samplesR;
    m_samplesL = samplesL;
}

void WaveformThread::deleteSamples()
{
    stopProcess();
    m_samplesL.clear();
    m_samplesR.clear();
}

void WaveformThread::setChannelCount(int channels)
{
    m_channelCount = channels;
}

void WaveformThread::processSamples(qreal window_wdith, qreal window_height, QColor wave_color, QColor background_color)
{

    m_width = window_wdith;
    m_heihgt = window_height;
    m_wave_color = wave_color;
    m_background_color = background_color;

    m_abort = false;
    start();
}

void WaveformThread::run()
{
    int numberOfSamples = m_samplesL.size();
    float xScale = (float)m_width / (numberOfSamples);
    float center = (float)m_heihgt / 2;
    QImage waveImage = QImage(m_width, m_heihgt, QImage::Format_RGB16);
    waveImage.fill(m_background_color);
    QPainter painter(&waveImage);
    painter.setPen(QPen(m_wave_color, 1, Qt::SolidLine, Qt::RoundCap));
    int counter = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < numberOfSamples; i++){
        if (m_abort)
            break;
        if (m_channelCount == 1)
            painter.drawRect(i * xScale, center - (m_samplesL[i] * center), 2, (m_samplesL[i] * center) * 2);
        else if (m_channelCount == 2)
        {
            painter.drawRect(i * xScale, (center / 2) - (m_samplesL[i] * (center / 2)), 2, (m_samplesL[i] * (center / 2)) * 2);
            painter.drawRect(i * xScale, ((center * 2)) - (m_samplesR[i] * (center / 2)), 2, (m_samplesR[i] * (center / 2)) * 2);
        }
        counter++;
    }
    emit waveformReady(waveImage);
}

void WaveformThread::stopProcess()
{
    mutex.lock();
    m_abort = true;
    mutex.unlock();
}
```

Comment: I would think, that the baseline of the second wave would be center + center/2 = 1.5*center instead of 2*center.

Comment: @Jens thanks, that's the answer. Well I've done it as `((center / 2) * 3)` but `center + center/2` seems better